# Why does tcl/tk hang at exit after invoking ftd2xx open (using tclftd2xx.dll) on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, tcl, ftdi

I have a Tcl/Tk app that I've developed on a Windows 8 machine.  The app uses the FTDI USB windows driver and tclftd2xx tcl extension to open the USB device.

As part of the testing I installed the app onto a windows 7 machine.  The app runs fine until I try to exit tcl.  When the exit command is executed the app just hangs.

I thought it was related to Tk, but it isn't. The tcl code is very simple (loc 22 is just an example):

```
package require ftd2xx
set handle [ftd2xx open -location 22]
exit
```

This isn't a "nice" hang -- even a program KILL will not shut it down.  The only way to get out of this is a hard reset of the machine since windows will not do a "safe" shut-down with active processes.

I did discover that invoking a ftd2xx reset would clear whatever it is tcl is waiting for, and allow the exit to complete.

As in:

```
package require ftd2xx
set handle [ftd2xx open -location 22]
ftd2xx reset $handle
exit
```

Now my problem is that if the user unplugs the USB device before closing the app, the file handle ($handle) goes stale, so the ftd2xx reset fails to release the hang, and I'm back to hard reboot.

I don't know if the error is in my initialization, in libftd2xx.c, in the FTDI drivers, or in Tcl.  I don't want to post all of libftd2xx.c

If anyone has some insight into this I'd appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Problem in the ftd2xx package I'd guess. Which doesn't help you. (Which exact version of Tcl are you using?)

Comment: sorry - it is tcl8.5.

Comment: Is there a way to explicitly kill the tcl event loop?  I'm going to try to build 8.6 and see if that helps.

Comment: The event loop doesn't run by default (unless you do `package require Tk` or use `wish`) and it never interrupts your code unless you use one of the commands that enters the event loop (`update`, `vwait` and things that call them, such as `http::geturl` without callbacks). Also, if you're dealing with threads them you're probably dealing with events, as inter-thread communications are routed via events…

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that:

1) the FTDI chip itself is configured in async-bit-bash mode.  According to the FTDI documentation, in this mode, the FTDI chip samples its parallel port pins (regardless of the direction (i/o) configuration), and writes the values to an internal buffer on each USB clock.

2) I was not using non-blocking reads (tcl channel configuration -blocking 0), because in this application, the USB is "write only".  (IE, each bit of the port is configured to an output, and each output drives an individual logic level to the board)

How it was solved:  configured the channel to non-blocking and defined a read handler that read the garbage.  Here is a code snippet - pardon the undefined variables; they are there for context.

```
.
.
.

set handle [ftd2xx open -location $loc]
chan configure $handle -blocking 0 -translation binary -0xFF01
fileevent $handle readable readhandler
.
.
proc readhandler {} {
  gets $handle junk
}
```

Indeed, readhandler is invoked quite often, and $junk sometimes has up to 10K bytes of data. After unplugging the USB, a subsequent "flush $filehandle" error is caught, allowing the program to shut down in an orderly fashion.